# how to create a menu item hide or visible

Tags: android

I want to create a menu the item, where when the item is clicked then he will disappears temporarily. as an example: I make a menu GpsOn and GpsOff, if the GpsOn clicked then he would disappears and the only remaining GpsOff, and conversely. is there any tutorial or code that can help me??

My Code :

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(isGpsOn){menu.getItem(MENU_GpsOn).setVisible(false);menu.getItem(MENU_GpsOff).setVisible(true);}
    else { menu.getItem(MENU_GpsOn).setVisible(true);menu.getItem(MENU_GpsOff).setVisible(false);}
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLogin();

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    String name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case MENU_Secure:
      try {
            sendSMS(name, "secure");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal karena " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return(true);
  case MENU_Unsecure:
      try {
            sendGPS(name, "notsec");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal karena " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return(true);
  case MENU_GpsOn:
      try {
            sendMobil(name, "gps on");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal karena " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      isGpsOn=true;
    //  ((MenuItem)findViewById(MENU_GpsOff)).setVisible(false);
   return(true);
  case MENU_GpsOff:
      try {
            sendGPSOff(name, "gpsoff");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gagal karena " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      isGpsOn=false;
       return(true);
  }
  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
 }
```

Comment: So what is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public boolean checkHide = false
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case GPS:
            if(checkHide){
                checkHide=false;
                item.setTitle("GPS_ON");
                  // ToDo your function

                }
            else{
                checkHide=true;
                item.setTitle("GPS_OFF");
                  // ToDo your function
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need is [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html). To create one such [button](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-simple-togglebutton-example.html), take a look at this tut [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/create-a-toggle-button/), as well as [this one](http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/toggle-button-in-android-with-an-example/) and [this one](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-toggle-button-example/).

This is of course, if I understood your requirements correctly.